# Installing snmp-mibs-downloader on debian 10 buster

Tags: debian, net-snmp, mib

I have installed net-snmp on a linux machine with debian 10 buster and now I need to install snmp-mibs-downloader.

Although I have previously run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

when executing:

```
sudo apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader
```

displays the following screen output, indicating that it cannot find the requested packet:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package snmp-mibs-downloader is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'snmp-mibs-downloader' has no installation candidate
```

I have seen on the internet that this could be solved by editing the file

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nonfree.list
```

But it does not explain what should be written in it.

Any help that allows me to install snmp-mibs-downloader is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

you /etc/apt/sources.list should be look like this:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
```

then do apt-get update

Comment: Ah, that solved it. It is the same for **bookworm**, and while you are editing the file, you maybe also want to add `non-free-firmware` the first item.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `non-free` repositories to your apt database then run `apt update`

See here: https://serverfault.com/a/240921/118361